# How to set alexnet from scratch?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I would train an alexnet DNN (given by MATLAB function `alexnet`) from scratch (i.e. without pretraining on ImageNet given by alexnet function). I could to manually set weights but I don't know the from what distribution I can sample my initial weights. Is there a built-in MATLAB option that make it for me?

For example, I've read that Python's library has the option `pre-training=off` but I don't find a similar option in MATLAB.